# How to show "incoming search terms"

Tags: search, 7

a lot of blogs have a feature to show the "incoming search terms" - it's great for SEO.
I looked up and down drupal.org but couldn't find a module.

Any recommendations on how to tackle this (I'm new to D7 and haven't built a module yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Google Analytics Reports](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module is very close to what you need, except it's currently only for Drupal 6. There is [an issue open](http://drupal.org/node/1016668) about porting it to Drupal 7, but it doesn't look very active.